# My website hosted on different server but I want to use Azure SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, azure

My website is hosted on a different server, but I want to use Azure SQL Server database, however I am getting this error:

> Cannot open server 'pollsurvey' requested by the login. Client with IP
>   address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' is not allowed to access the server.  To
>   enable access, use the Windows Azure Management Portal or run
>   sp_set_firewall_rule on the master database to create a firewall rule
>   for this IP address or address range.  It may take up to five minutes
>   for this change to take effect

I added my url in Azure firewall near about 1 day before but my issue is not resolved yet. Anyone have idea what can I do.

Comment: What about this error message do you not understand?  I'm actually impressed that Microsoft has such a clear message with an explanation of how to handle the error.

Comment: I know the message i have add that ip in azure firewall but that is not working

Answer (score 0):

Your connection is blocked by the Azure firewall

Go to the portal and add the Web server IP to the firewall rules of your SQL Azure server.

Answer (score 0):

Johann's answer is correct, I am just providing the screenshot :)

[image]

Comment: i was add my IP near about 1 day before but issue is not resolved

Comment: Do you have "Allow access to Azure Services" turned on?  Is your website hosted in Azure?

Comment: Yes "Allow access to Azure Services" turned on. But website not hosted on azure server that is different one you can check following url mypoll.antisoftindia.com

Comment: You need to add the public up address of your website to the allowed list then.

Comment: Yes is have added the static IP there

Comment: @satnamsingh What IP have you added? Can you post it here?

Comment: Honestly @satnamsingh, I think you may need to reach out to Azure Support via the portal.  Something is missing from the list of information because everything we have told you should work.